# How to Implement {script}folder/file{/script}

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am looking to build a plugin for Joomla that will allow me to play video using HTML5 first before resorting back to Flash. In my effort to make this plugin in more dynamic I would like to have an easy way of embedding the video. In similar plugins I have seen where the user can put in a specific phrase surrounded with brackets. Something similar to the following:

```
{html5video}media/video{/html5video}
```

What is this method called and where can I find more information on how to implement it into a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no specific term defined in Joomla for this method, but those who are much familiar with Wordpress calls it SHORTCODE method

You will need to create a content plugin - 
use regex , php `preg_match_all` and extract this string and replace with your desired code.

One such plugin is available in Joomla. You can check it in plugins\content\loadmodule

You may need to modify the regex pattern used in this plugin